# datetime conversion and manipulation in python

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

My raw data is in CSV. I load it as a pandas dataframe and datetime fields are loaded as objects.

```
datetime1   22773 non-null object
datetime2   22771 non-null object
```

Using `pd.to_datetime(df['datetime1'])` I convert it to - `datetime64[ns]`.

But in doing so the actual value is increased by 7 hours.

I have 2 questions -

1. What is the unit `datetime64[ns]`? is it based on unix time or some other time zone?
2. How can I subtract the 7 hours and keep the actual value but my field format is still datetime?

Comment: That's interesting.  Would you mind posting your original data frame or least the date time fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's just a data type that's based on numpy's datetime64[ns].  It doesn't contain a timezone attribute that altered your data
2. `df["existing or new column"] = df["datetime1] - pd.Timedelta(7, 'h')`

Also, you can always convert to date time when you read the csv using the parse_dates parameter like so.  That way to can skip the pd.to_datetime() step

```
df = pd.read_csv("filename", parse_dates = ["datetime1","datetime2"])
```